Flutter X Firebase Cloud Messaging X Firebase Cloud Functions
I'm currently developing a to-do app in Flutter that uses Firebase as a backend. I want to incorporate notifications and reminders for tasks, and since I'm already using Firebase Auth, Hosting, App Distributor, Storage, and Firestore, I'd like to stay within the Firebase ecosystem to add notification functionality.
To achieve this, I plan on using Firebase Cloud Functions to verify every minute if there is a notification that needs to be triggered and Firebase Cloud Messaging to send the notification.
However, I've run into some issues trying to add notifications to my app, despite following several YouTube tutorials. So, I'm reaching out for help.
I'm not familiar with TypeScript, JavaScript, or Python, which are the three languages available for Firebase Cloud Functions. I only know Python, but I'm open to learning a new language if it would be better suited to this use case.
Here is the architecture of my Firebase Firestore database:

"Users": A collection that contains every user.
"wSBX4D0U3PU...": A unique ID specific to a user.
"Tasks": A collection that contains every task of a user.
"s1mnK11qMbzu": A unique ID specific to a task.
Each task in the "Tasks" collection has the following information:

title (String): The title of the task.
description (String): The description of the task.
state (bool): True if the task is done, false if not.
theme (String): The theme of the task.

To send a notification to a user, I need to save their FCM Token in their document. I can do this myself.
I also need to include a specific DateTime for each task when a notification needs to be sent. I plan on using a DateTimePicker in my Flutter interface when creating a task.
Given all the pieces of information needed to send a notification - the FCM Token of the user and the date when a notification needs to be sent - my questions are:

Which language should I use for my Firebase Cloud Functions: TypeScript, JavaScript, or Python?
How do I write a Firebase Cloud Function that loops every minute to check if a task needs to trigger a notification? If a notification needs to be sent, how do I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send the notification to the correct user, with the title of the task as the title of the notification?

I hope that's clear enough, but please let me know if you need more information. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
